# What is the solution to the set $A$ to the power of $3$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In my textbook I am being asked the to solve $A^3$ for the following two questions:

1. $A = \{a\}$
2. $A = \{0, a\}$

So for question `1.` I would have something that would look like this: $\{a\} * \{a\} * \{a\}$. Wouldn't this just give me a set full of $a$'s? And since in sets we don't have duplicate values, I think the answer is simply $a$, but I feel like that seems too simple?

And for the second part I think I need to start the answer off like this:

$$\{(0,a), (a,0)\}*\{a\}$$

From here though I am unsure how to finish completing the solution.

Comment: It's unlikely, but possible, that the text you're following defines $A^3:=A^2\times A$. I'd expect $A^3:=\{(x,y,z)\colon x,y,z\in A\}$.

Comment: @GitGud I assume your way is probably right of it being $x,y,z$. That would mean that I would get $\{(a,a,a)\}$ doesn't it?

Comment: No, $x,y,z\in A$ is short for $x\in A\land y\in A\land z\in A$. So, for instance, $0\in A\land 0\in A\land a\in A$ is true, which implies that $(0,0,a)\in A^3$. The set $A^3$ has eight elements.

Comment: @GitGud I am confused where the 0's and 1's are coming from regarding the first question? Is $(0,0,1)$ the binary truth values?

Comment: I'm sorry, $1$ was a typo which is now fixed and I was talking about the second question. Your answer for the first one is correct.

Comment: @GitGud ah okay that makes more sense then. So regarding the second one I am essentially trying to cover all of the possible combinations of filling in 3 spots with a $0$ or an $a$. Is that a fair way to look at it?

Comment: Yes, it is.${}$

Comment: @GitGud okay, your comment has answered my question it seems so feel free to put it into an answer if you'd like and I can mark it as accepted :)

Comment: I'd rather not. I suggest you wait a day or two and if no one answers, you answer it yourself.

Comment: @GitGud okay, whatever works best for you :). Thanks for the help!

Comment: @GitGud one clarification: when you said my answer to the first question was right, you were referring to my answer in the comment, not the original post, correct?

Comment: Yes, $\{(a,a,a)\}$ is correct.